# Oracle parallel hint on cluster

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, parallel-processing, query-optimization

I wanted to use the parallel hint that would give the best performance in my query which is a equi-join query where the two tables are in a cluster and the join column is a cluster index.

I wasn't sure if I should use the parallel option on one of the tables `PARALLEL(table1, 4)`, both of the tables `PARALLEL(4)` or on the clusters index `PARALLEL_INDEX(index_name, 4)`?

Here was my query:

```
SELECT /*+ USE_HASH(a, b)  */a.name, b.price
FROM Customer a, Sales b 
WHERE b.Cust_id < 2000 
AND b.Cust_id = a.Cust_id;
```

Here is the execution plan for this query:

[image]

Comment: Why not just test the runtimes of all of these options?

Comment: Are they set up as single table hash clusters, or just two tables on the same cluster

Comment: just two tables in a cluster